# Outputs string if string contains vowels and is in alphabetical order

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, sorting

I'm working on the following exercise below:

Write a method, `ovd(str)` that takes a string of lowercase words and returns a string with just the words containing all their vowels (excluding "y") in alphabetical order. Vowels may be repeated (`"afoot"` is an ordered vowel word). The method does not return the word if it is not in alphabetical order.

Example output is:

> ovd("this is a test of the vowel ordering system") #output=> "this is a test of the system"
>
> ovd("complicated") #output=> ""

Below is code I wrote that will do the job but I am looking to see if there is a shorter more clever way to do this. My solution seems too lengthy.Thanks in advance for helping.

```
def ovd?(str) 
  u=[] 
  k=str.split("")   
  v=["a","e","i","o","u"]
  w=k.each_index.select{|i| v.include? k[i]}
  r={}
  for i in 0..v.length-1
     r[v[i]]=i+1
  end
  w.each do |s|
     u<<r[k[s]]
  end
   if u.sort==u 
      true
  else 
      false
  end

end

def ovd(phrase) 
  l=[]
  b=phrase.split(" ") 
  b.each do |d|
    if ovd?(d)==true
    l<<d 
    end
  end
  p l.join(" ") 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def ovd(str)
  str.split.select { |word| "aeiou".match(/#{word.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars.uniq.join(".*")}/) }.join(" ")
end
ovd("this is a test of the vowel ordering system") # => "this is a test of the system"
ovd("complicated") # => ""
ovd("alooft") # => "alooft"
ovd("this is testing words having something in them") # => "this is testing words having in them"
```

### EDIT

As requested by the OP, explanation

[String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) word.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "") removes the non-vowel characters e.g
    "afloot".gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "") # => "aoo"
[String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chars) converts the new word to an array of characters

```
"afloot".gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars # => ["a", "o", "o"]
```

[Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) converts returns only unique elements from the array e.g

```
"afloot".gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars.uniq # => ["a", "o"]
```

[Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-join) converts an array to a string merging it with the supplied parameter e.g

```
"afloot".gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars.uniq.join(".*") # => "a.*o"
```

#{} is simply [String interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) and // converts the interpolated string into a Regular Expression

```
/#{"afloot".gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars.uniq.join(".*")}/ # => /a.*o/
```

Comment: Wow! That's awesome! You reduced my 20+ lines of code to 3 lines! Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: @user3145336 note I updated my answer, to catch repeating vowels

Comment: Thanks! I think str.split.select { |word| "aeiou".match(word.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars.to_a.uniq.join(".*"))}.join(" ") works as well =)

Comment: @user3145336 chars as returned an array already no need to call to_a on it

Comment: when I do word.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars: #=> <Enumerator: "aoo":chars>. Only when I do word.gsub(/[^aeiou]/, "").chars.to_a #=> ["a", "o", "o"]. Perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @user3145336 you are probably using a version of ruby less than 2.0

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: `ovd("leisure") # => "leisure"`, as `uniq` is chucking out the second `e`, which is the only vowel that is out of order.

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution:

```
V = %w[a e i o u] # => ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  def ovd(str)
    str.split.select{|w| (x = w.downcase.chars.select \
      {|c| V.include?(c)}) == x.sort}.join(' ')
  end

  ovd("this is a test of the vowel ordering system")
                                          # => "this is a test of the system"
  ovd("")                                 # => ""
  ovd("camper")                           # => "camper" 
  ovd("Try singleton")                    # => "Try"
  ovd("I like leisure time")              # => "I" 
  ovd("The one and only answer is '42'")  # => "The and only answer is '42'"
  ovd("Oil and water don't mix")          # => "and water don't mix"
```

Edit to add an alternative:

```
NV = (0..127).map(&:chr) - %w(a e i o u) # All ASCII chars except lc vowels

def ovd(str)
  str.split.select{|w| (x = w.downcase.chars - NV) == x.sort}.join(' ')
end
```

Note `x = w.downcase.chars & V` does not work. While it spears out the vowels from `w`, and preserves their order, it removes duplicates.